# Catch using of Monolog\Logger methods

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

I need to add some action, when application runs one of Monolog\Logger methods (info, error, warning etc.) and do some custom code.

for example:

```
$this->logger->error('Some error');
```

should do error output - basic action for Monolog\Logger, but after that send error text via API ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Symfony Monolog documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html) and check out if you find any [network or server handler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#log-specific-servers-and-networked-logging) from the list of [included handlers and their configuration options](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L25).

If there is no suitable handler you should create a custom handler class using the [service handler type](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L27), e.g. `src/AppBundle/Monolog/YourApiHandler.php` which needs to implement at least the [HandlerInterface](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/HandlerInterface.php) , but you could also see if another class you could inherit from is more appropriate for your task, e.g. [AbstractProcesssingHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php) .

Once you have implemented your handler just define a service for it

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    my_handler:
        class: AppBundle\Monolog\YourApiHandler
```

and add it to the monolog configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        my_handler:
            type: service
            id: my_handler
```